# Issue with persistent data and handling

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-persistence

OK, first let me describe you my situation :

- I have a list of books (let's say `List<Book> Books`)
- For each book, we need several details, e.g. Author, Title, etc

**Now, here's the deal :**

- I've set up a full catalog (as XML), which I'm able to deserialize as objects. (e.g. when the app is loading)

**What I need :**

- The data (e.g. book details) are not fixed - some details could be edited/updated later on.
- Be able to store this data, so that when the app opens up again the data is still there
- Be able to access this data from no-matter-which page
- Be able to easily add Bindings to this data, so that I can e.g. show a list of `Book`s in the GUI.

What would be the best way to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You consider the sql? For example Sqlite. You just need few tables and relations and it's very flexible. For even more flexibility you can use versioning xml in records for details.